# Matrix vs Tensor vs Array vs Set

Tags: matrices, terminology, tensors

Consider the following vector $\vec x$:

$$\vec x= \vec e_a x^a $$

$$x^a= \left(
\begin{matrix}
A \\
D \\
G \\
\end{matrix}
\right) $$

$$x^1= A, x^2=D,x^3=G $$

$$\vec e_1= \hat i ,\vec e_2=\hat j, \vec e_3=\hat k $$

$$\vec e_1= \left(
\begin{matrix}
\hat i & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right) 
=  \left(
\begin{matrix}
1 &
0 &
0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)  \left(
\begin{matrix}
\hat i \\
\end{matrix}
\right) = e_1 \hat i  $$

$$\vec e_2= \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & \hat j & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right) 
=  \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 &
1 &
0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)  \left(
\begin{matrix}
\hat j \\
\end{matrix}
\right) = e_2 \hat j  $$

$$\vec e_3= \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & \hat k \\
\end{matrix}
\right) 
=  \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 &
0 &
1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)  \left(
\begin{matrix}
\hat k \\
\end{matrix}
\right) = e_3 \hat k  $$

$$ \vec x= \vec e_1 A+ \vec e_2 D + \vec e_3 G \quad or \quad \vec x= \left(\vec e_1 A+ \vec e_2 D + \vec e_3 G \right)_{1x1} $$

$$ \vec x= \vec e_1 x^1+ \vec e_2 x^2 + \vec e_3 x^3 $$

$$ \vec x= \left(
\begin{matrix}
\vec e_1 & \vec e_2 & \vec e_3 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)_{1x3} \left(
\begin{matrix}
x^1 \\
x^2 \\
x^3 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)_{3x1}
 $$

$$\vec x= \left(
\begin{matrix}
e_1 \hat i & e_2 \hat j & e_3 \hat k \\
\end{matrix}
\right)_{1x3} \left(
\begin{matrix}
x^1 \\
x^2 \\
x^3 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)_{3x1}$$

$$\vec x= \left(
\begin{matrix}
e_1 & e_2 & e_3 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)_{1x3} 
\left(\begin{matrix}
\hat i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \hat j & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \hat k \\
\end{matrix}
\right)_{3x3}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x^1 \\
x^2 \\
x^3 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)_{3x1}$$

Now I am going to say my opinion about the above. **Please do correct me if I am wrong in this paragraph.**
In the above, the 3x3 matrix is a tensor of rank 3.But the 1x3 & 3x1 matrices are matrices of column vector- & row vector- components respectively. Vector is a tensor of rank 1. Vector components are usually written as a matrix of only 1 column (or as a column matrix of scalars). These components are contravariant.Co-vector components are usually written as a matrix of only 1 row (or as a row matrix of scalars).These components are co-variant.The basis vectors of a vector are co-variant. 
A matrix of vector components $\neq$ vector. ie $ x^a \neq \vec x $ But the matrix product of matrix with vector components ($x^a$) & matrix with basis vectors ($\vec e_a \quad or \quad (\vec e_1 \quad \vec e_2 \quad \vec e_3)$) is a vector. The matrix with basis vectors $( \vec e_1 \quad \vec e_2 \quad \vec e_3)$ is not a vector. But it is just the matrix product of the matrix with basis vector components $(e_1 \quad e_2 \quad e_3)$ & the tensor $\left(\begin{matrix} \hat i & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \hat j & 0 \\ 0 & 0& \hat k\\ \end{matrix}\right)$. And a matrix product is a matrix too.

Now, consider the following matrix where all its components are scalars:

$$ Q_M=\left(
\begin{matrix}
A & B & C\\
D & E & F\\
G & H & I\\
\end{matrix}
\right) $$

And consider the following 3x3  matrix with components which are vectors:

$$ \left(
\begin{matrix}
A \\
B\\
C\\
\end{matrix}
\right) 
\left(\begin{matrix}
\hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
\end{matrix}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
A\hat i & A\hat j & A\hat k\\
B\hat i & B\hat j & B\hat k\\
C\hat i & C\hat j & C\hat k\\
\end{matrix}
\right)_{3x3} = Q_{T1}$$

Also consider the following matrix with components which are vectors:

$$ Q_{T2}= \left(
\begin{matrix}
A\hat i & B\hat j & C\hat k\\
D\hat i & E\hat j & F\hat k\\
G\hat i & H\hat j & I\hat k\\
\end{matrix}
\right) $$

**Is it correct if I say $Q_M$ is just a matrix(& not a tensor) but $Q_{T1}$ & $Q_{T2}$ are tensors?** And the reason why I say so is because $Q_M$ has components that are purely scalars but $Q_{T1}$ & $Q_{T2}$ have components with different magnitude & direction. Its similar to saying $x^a$ is not a vector but $\vec x$ is a vector & that $x^a$ is just a column matrix of vector components.
If a matrix couldn't be written as a matrix product of column matrix (of contravariant components) & row matrix (of covariant components) (eg- matrix of basis vectors) ,then is it not then a tensor? 
 **Is it also correct if I believe not all matrices are tensors ,not all tensors are matrices ,not all arrays are matrices (a matrix is a 2 dimensional array),all matrices are arrays ,not all arrays are tensors ,all tensors are arrays, not all sets are arrays & all arrays are sets?**

Comment: A matrix, if it represents a tensor, is always a tensor of rank 2 (one variant rank and one covariant, usually). Rank 3 tensors correspond to 3-dimensional tables of numbers, while a single row or a single column is a rank 1 tensor.

Comment: @ Arthur- If a matrix couldn't be written as a matrix product of column matrix (of contravariant components) & row matrix (of covariant components) (eg- matrix of basis vectors) ,then it is not a tensor, right? But can you give any example?

Comment: So if a matrix couldn't be written as matrix product of even atleast 1 covariant & 1 contravariant component or atleast 2 covariant components or atleast 2 contravariant components without any additional term, I guess  its not a tensor.